# Using Orphan branches to host a project on gh-pages

Tags: git, github, github-pages

**My use-case:**

I am working on a hobby project which contains multiple mini-projects. Instead of creating a separate repo for every single mini-project, I thought to **create a single repo with multiple `orphan branches`**, so as to keep all the mini-projects with un-related histories and belong to single repo (**repo is based on a language or a framework**).

**Question:**

In addition to the above use-case, I also want to host each of my `orphan branches` to `gh-pages` separately. I know how to manage a repo with multiple orphan branches. But I wanted to know if it is possible to host multiple orphan branches onto `gh-pages` from a single repo?

**My Inputs:**

1. I am aware of how to create and manage multiple orphan branches in a single repo.
2. I want to completely isolate histories of each of my mini-projects that's why I chose to use orphan-branches.
3. I am aware of how to host static websites and docs on `gh-pages`.

Any suggestions would really be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Considering a [GitHub Pages configuration source](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site) is for *one* repository, you would still need one repo per project.

But that does not mean you cannot maintain them all from *one* "parent" repository.

You could add each gh-pages branch of each of those project/pages repositories as a [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) of one parent repo:

```
cd path/to/parent
git submodule add -b gh-pages /url/project1
git submodule add -b gh-pages /url/project2
...
```

In each `projectx` folder, you can:

- fetch and switch to the `gh-pages` branch
- work, add and commit, and push

Once you are done, go back to the parent main folder, add, commit and push, to record all the submodules new tree.

The idea remains: in one cloned repository, you can work on *all* your `gh-pages` branches projects.

Comment: Thank you so much for your insightful post. I had a query though. If I use submodules will  the histories of each mini-projects (i.e. **branches**) be unrelated if we see the source-tree of parent?

Comment: @Mandy8055 Yes. The parent repo only records their latest evolution, but each branch remains independent.